# Por que e quando usar XML em vez de JSON?

Tags: json, xml

O JSON tem pelo menos duas vantagens em relação ao XML:

1. O *parsing* é mais rápido
2. Ocupa menos *bytes*

Ainda assim tem gente que prefere o XML. Existe algum motivo para preferir XML? Ou em que situações ele é mais adequado (e porque)?

Comment: Uma dúvida... Esta questão pode ser baseada em opinião?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta ficaria melhor se fosse usado "Por que e quando"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A decisão entre se usar XML ou JSON é mais ou menos como escolher entre um banco de dados relacional ou um NoSQL: tudo se resume a decidir sobre um **esquema explícito** ou **implícito**.

Um **esquema** (*schema*) é uma descrição de um conjunto de dados (i.e. meta-dados). Ele determina o tipo desses dados, seu formato, a relação entre eles, como eles estão estruturados, etc. Se esses dados são para consumo humano, o esquema não importa tanto - já que temos a capacidade de ler e interpretar o conteúdo à nossa frente ainda que o mesmo esteja mal-estruturado e "bagunçado". Mas se os dados são para consumo da máquina (i.e. serão lidos e manipulados por outros programas) então um esquema formal *sempre* será necessário - esteja ele codificado em meta-dados ou apenas convencionado.

Assim como em um BD relacional você precisa criar as tabelas, definir suas colunas, suas chaves e restrições, etc, um arquivo XML pode conter o mesmo tipo de descrição (na forma de um DTD ou de um Schema) - dizendo que elementos são aceitos, quais atributos e sub-elementos eles podem ter, etc. Dessa forma, é possível *automatizar* o processo de verificar se um dado XML é ou não válido de acordo com sua especificação. Ou seja, da mesma forma como você não pode atribuir uma coluna que não existe num BD, você não pode criar um elemento que não existe no esquema e o XML ainda ser válido.

Por outro lado, é possível se criar um XML sem esquema - onde todo conteúdo é válido desde que a sintaxe esteja correta. Ficaria portanto de responsabilidade do programador garantir que esse conteúdo fosse gerado e consumido segundo uma regra lógica. Se for o mesmo programador fazendo os dois lados, é fácil, pois ao mudar um ele saberá que tem que mudar o outro (não dá pra consumir o que não existe, ou produzir algo pra ninguém). Mas se for uma equipe grande - ou pior, um conjunto de equipes ou mesmo de organizações distintas - é mais difícil controlar as alterações e garantir que todos os sub-sistemas envolvidos tratem delas corretamente.

Entretanto, se pelas características particulares de uma situação um esquema explícito não é mesmo necessário, por que não ainda usar XML? Nesse caso, as *desvantagens* do XML tornam ele uma solução menos que ideal - a sintaxe é verbosa (toda tag aberta tem que ser fechada), os arquivos se tornam grandes e portanto difíceis de ler e escrever, e o processamento de XML é mais difícil e lento. Nesse caso, uma solução mais "leve" é preferível - da mesma maneira de um BD *schema-less* será mais simples de usar e terá melhor desempenho do que um BD relacional tentando tratar de dados arbitrários, sem estrutura.

O JSON se mostrou uma solução adequada para esses casos. Não é a única, nem necessariamente a melhor (na Wikipedia em inglês há um [comparativo entre diversos formatos de serialização de dados](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)), mas como muitas vezes o lado "cliente" da comunicação é um *browser* - e portanto suporta JavaScript nativamente - essa proximidade adicional entre o formato e os literais da própria linguagem trouxe a vantagem adicional de simplificar bastante o código cliente*. Creio que esse foi um fator decisivo para consolidar o JSON como a alternativa "leve" preferida ao XML. E uma vez que ele passou a receber amplo suporte na maioria das plataformas, sua ubiquidade aumentou ainda mais sua vantagem.

<sub>* Digo isso em termos históricos: antigamente se usava o próprio `eval` do JavaScript para se interpretar JSON, mas depois que a ameaça de XSS ficou evidente e bem conhecida, passou-se a usar funções próprias para fazer a conversão JS-JSON.</sub>

Comment: É interessante acrescentar que o XML e JSON devem coexistir e evoluir juntos por algum tempo, e talvez adquiram menos importância se tratados em uma camada de abstração mais alta, a do *modelo de dados*. A especificação [XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) que deve sair este ano propõe recursos de transformação para construir modelos de dados que tratam JSON e XML de forma equivalente, podendo-se validar e pesquisar JSON ou XML usando XPath.

Comment: Também existem iniciativas como [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) e [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) buscam trazer para o JSON algumas das facilidades populares que existem no mundo XML.

Answer (score 9):

### JSON:

O objeto JSON é por vezes utilizado como "ponte de comunicação", pois ele é leve e rápido, diferente do XML que possui uma estrutura mais aguçada. A maneira que o objeto JSON é manipulado também é uma das facilidades de organização, tornando o código mais limpo e dedicado apenas à estrutura de dados. Veja um exemplo em ActionScript:

```
var json:Object = {nome: "João", idade: 18, veiculos: ["Twister", "BMW"], parentes: {mae: "Maria", pai: "Joaquim"}};
```

Isso sem falar que é possível inserir um Array diretamente em um item, assim como outro objeto JSON.

Essa facilidade de manipulação junto com a rapidez/leveza é um dos motivos principais que faz do JSON a ferramenta perfeita para comunicação de dados com servidor.

### XML:

Acredito que o XML possa funcionar como um "mini-bd", gravando algumas informações cruciais para desenvolvimento de algum sistema, seja local ou web.

O sistema de gerenciamento de dados é um pouco mais estruturada, onde você pode adicionar parâmetros e valores em um determinado item, como abaixo:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(
    <root>
        <atualizacao data="06/06/2014"></atualizacao>
        <nome>João</nome>
        <idade>18</idade>
        <veiculos>
            <veiculo>Twister</veiculo>
            <veiculo>BMW</veiculo>
        </veiculos>
        <parentes>
            <pai>Joaquim</pai>
            <mae>Maria<mae>
        <parentes>
        
    </root>
);
```

Embora a estrutura de um XML seja organizada e bem compreendida, a interação com a Web pode deixar um pouco mais a desejar, pelo fato de ser um pouco mais complicada de se trabalhar para resgatar todas essas informações, tirando o fato que você não tem como aderir à um objeto Array dentro de um nó, criando diversos nós com nome idêntico.

Como eu resgataria essas duas informações:

```
trace(json["nome"]); //"João"
trace(xml.nome); //"João"

trace(json["veiculos"]); //[Twister, BMW]

trace(xml.veiculos); //<veiculo>Twister</veiculo><veiculo>BMW</veiculo>
trace(xml.veiculos.veiculo[0]); //Twister
trace(xml.veiculos.veiculo[1]); //BMW

trace(xml.atualizacao.@data); //06/06/2014
```

Sim, há essas diferenças entre eles que podem influenciar no resultado final do seu sistema.

Comment: `JSON tem uma facilidade incrível de organizar informações` O que faz ele ter essa facilidade? `JSON não é o mais adequado para guardar informações` Por que o XML seria mais adequado?

Comment: Editei a resposta!

Answer (score 5):

O XML apresenta diversas facilidades e usos que o JSON não suporta.

Você pode ter busca nele através de [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/), [XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xQuery/default.asp) além de poder validar [Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/) ( saber se está bem formado ) e [muitas outras coisas](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp).

Há espaço para as duas tecnologias, sendo o XML mais robusto ( e burocrático ) e o JSON mais leve ( e menos controlável? )

Answer (score 3):

Depende do contexto, meu caro. Se você está considerando escolher entre um deles para expor resultados de uma API, por exemplo, vai depender do padrão da sua API. Normalmente, API's Restful tendem a utilizar JSON, enquanto web services no padrão WSDL usam o XML.

O XML, por seguir um padrão de marcação, vai lhe permitir mais flexibilidade, enquanto o JSON é um padrão mais simples e direto – e atualmente mais aceito no contexto web, principalmente quando se fala de [single-page applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).