# E em que contexto o uso de JSON pode ser vantajoso em relação ao uso de XML (em aplicações web)?

Tags: json, xml, aplicação-web

Tenho essa pergunta em um simulado de prova. Além da facilidade de escrita do Json, e do fato de ser bem orientado a objetos, quais poderiam ser as vantagens?

O tópico: [Por que e quando usar XML em vez de JSON?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19423/por-que-e-quando-usar-xml-em-vez-de-json)  Não me ajudou, pois preciso de mais informação sobre as vantagens do Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JSON

> O objeto JSON é por vezes utilizado como "ponte de comunicação", pois ele é leve e rápido, diferente do XML que possui uma estrutura mais aguçada. A maneira que o objeto JSON é manipulado também é uma das facilidades de organização, tornando o código mais limpo e dedicado apenas à estrutura de dados. 
>   Isso sem falar que é possível inserir um Array diretamente em um item, assim como outro objeto JSON.
>
> Essa facilidade de manipulação junto com a rapidez/leveza é um dos motivos principais que faz do JSON a ferramenta perfeita para comunicação de dados com servidor.

### XML

> Acredito que o XML possa funcionar como um "mini-bd", gravando algumas informações cruciais para desenvolvimento de algum sistema, seja local ou web.
>    O sistema de gerenciamento de dados é um pouco mais estruturada, onde você pode adicionar parâmetros e valores em um determinado item.
>
> Embora a estrutura de um XML seja organizada e bem compreendida, a interação com a Web pode deixar um pouco mais a desejar, pelo fato de ser um pouco mais complicada de se trabalhar para resgatar todas essas informações, tirando o fato que você não tem como aderir à um objeto Array dentro de um nó, criando diversos nós com nome idêntico.

### ALGUMAS VANTAGENS DO JSON

> 1. O parsing é mais rápido
> 2. Ocupa menos bytes (MAIS LEVE)

`Resposta baseada neste` [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19423/por-que-e-quando-usar-xml-em-vez-de-json)