# Diferenças entre usar XML ou JSON

Tags: json, xml

Quero entender por que usar XML ou JSON, e porque tem pouco conteúdo de XML na internet? XML já está "morto"?

Comment: O questionamento é totalmente válido. Talvez tenha faltado somente fontes das afirmações feitas na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML está longe de ter morrido, ainda tem um absurdo de coisas em XML, incluindo aí suas variações como [XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) só para citar um exemplo (tem várias outras com propósito semelhante), muitos arquivos de configuração usam. XML foi criado para ser extensível e não para ser usado de forma pura porque é simples demais. XML tem uma série de recursos que JSON não tem, por exemplo você *tipar* os dados com *schema* e uso de *namespace*, e torná-lo [canônico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).

JSON é muito mais simples e foi criado justamente pra isso, quando você não precisa de tudo o que XML precisa. JSON é usado pela maioria das APIs por ser mais leve que XML para transportar e até para construir e decodificar, o ganho pode impactar em grandes volumes.

De forma geral se é para usar algo simples então a pessoa poderia usar algo diferente como [YAML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80881/101) e algo parecido, mas o JSON pegou e as pessoas não costumam questionar porque estão usando aquilo, quase todo mundo acha que se está todo mundo usando deve usar também. Claro que se vai trocar dados com terceiros então adotar o padrão é importante. O YAML tem lá suas desvantagens, então um outro formato, talvez proprietário, seja mais interessante para seu caso.

XML é usado para coisas que precisam de mais confiabilidade, segurança e estabilidade, um dos exemplos que mais usamos é nas questões fiscais do Brasil (NFe e companhia) e em muitas plataformas [EDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) tradicionais.

O fato de você ver pouco conteúdo é só uma tendenciosidade sua, é assim que nascem as *fake news*, a pessoa considera que sua percepção é mais importante que o fato.

Pode ver mais em [Por que e quando usar XML em vez de JSON?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19423/101).

| JSON | XML |
| --- | --- |
| Simples | Complexo e poderoso |
| Fácil de parsear | Difícil |
| Rápido para parsear | Lento |
| Mapa de mapas | Árvore |
| Dados sem semântica | Informação semântica |
| Sem cerimônia | Maior controle |
| Schemaless (implicitude) | Schema (explicitude) |
| Só dados | Metadados |
| Uso bruto livre | Mecanismo sofisticado |
| Sem namespace | Namespace |
| Formato de transferência de dados | Linguagem de marcação |
| Nasceu do uso com JavaScript | Derivado de SGML |
| Fácil de aprender | Difícil |
| Dados livres | Documento |
| "Inconfiável" | "Confiável" |
| Legível | "Ilegível" |
| Dados básicos | Dados ricos |
| Permite array | Simula array |
| Sem Comentários | Comentários |
| UTF-8 padrão | Configurável |
| Pouco espaço | Desperdício |
| Serialização | Configuração/Validação |

Claro que algumas dessas coisas são opcionais ou podem ser solucionadas com algum adendo que a tecnologia permite e que alguém fez, por exemplo ter um *schema* no JSON. Nem tudo que parece é necessariamente ruim. Por exemplo, se compactar os dados o XML fica do mesmo tamanho do JSON compactado, mas claro que JSON demora menos para compactar.

XML tem perdido mercado, mas isso é morrer?

[image: Google trends de XML X JSON]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Desculpa por não ter feito uma pergunta caprichada. rs
Mas fico no aguardo do restante do conteúdo, estou começando a entender melhor. Muito Obrigado amigo.